# Maximum length of String attribute in Core Data entity using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I want to find the word with maximum characters of an entity attribute.  I am trying to create a sort descriptor to compare string lengths.  The code compiles, but I get the error `unsupported NSSortDescriptor selector: comparatorOfStringLengths` when the fetch query is executed.  I tried the comparator block version of `NSSortDescriptor` but it is unsupported.

```
            query.sortDescriptors = [
                NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "word", ascending: false, selector: #selector(NSString.comparatorOfStringLengths))
            ]
```

Below is the latest version of the signature of the comparator method.  I tried also using a `static` func with two arguments, and with `Any` instead of `String` as well, I get same result.  I modeled this signature on the `func localizedStandardCompare(_ string: String) -> ComparisonResult` standard func.

```
extension NSString {   
    @objc func comparatorOfStringLengths(_ b: String) -> ComparisonResult {
        if self.length < b.length {
            return .orderedAscending
        }
        if self.length > b.length {
            return .orderedDescending
        }
        return .orderedSame
    }
}
```

Screenshot of error:
[image]

EDIT: I adjusted/corrected the signature of selector specifier but this also fails:
`#selector(NSString.comparatorOfStringLengths(_:)))`

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong about that but i think with Core Data (iOS 13) such a `NSPredicate` and `NSSortDescriptor` as you would like it is still not possible.

An option might be to add an additional attribute `wordlen` of number type that holds the length of `word`. And fetch the entity with the highest value for `wordlen`.

For further explanation i quickly switch to my *Person* standards example with the entity `Person` with a string attribute `name` (corresponds to `word` in OP) and an integer attribute `namelen`.

With the new function `validateNamelen` that will be placed where the `Person` code was generated:

```
extension Person {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Person> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var namelen: NSNumber?

    @objc func validateNamelen(_ ioValue: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) throws {
        ioValue.pointee = NSNumber.init(integerLiteral: name!.count)
    }

}
```

that will be triggered by Core Data and helps to synchronize the value of `namelen` with newly created or updated `Person` entities.

Then adding an index `NameLenIndex` on `namelen` makes the fetch faster:

[image]

**Swift 5** Code for evaluation:

```
    // Create Persons
    var personObj: Person = Person(context: mainContext)
    personObj.name = "Person1 A"
    personObj = Person(context: mainContext)
    personObj.name = "Person2 BB"
    personObj = Person(context: mainContext)
    personObj.name = "Person3 CCC"
    personObj = Person(context: mainContext)
    personObj.name = "Person4 A"
    personObj = Person(context: mainContext)
    personObj.name = "Person5 BB"
    personObj = Person(context: mainContext)
    personObj.name = "Person6 CCC"
    saveContext()

    // Get person
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

    // Which persons?
    let predicateMax = NSPredicate(format: "namelen==max(namelen)")
    let predicateMin = NSPredicate(format: "namelen==min(namelen)")

    // Persons with longest names
    request.predicate = predicateMin;

    print("Persons with shortes Names:")
    do {
        let results = try mainContext.fetch(request)
        for result in results {
            print(result.name ?? "No name found")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }

    request.predicate = predicateMax;

    print("Persons with longest Names:")
    do {
        let results = try mainContext.fetch(request)
        for result in results {
            print(result.name ?? "No name found")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```

Given an empty database at the beginning the output is like this:

```
Persons with shortes Names:
Person1 A
Person4 A
Persons with longest Names:
Person6 CCC
Person3 CCC
```